# Understanding the bra-ket antilinear correspondence

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, vectors, definition, notation

[image]

I can't follow how the above argument leads to (1.8).

I am able to prove it only if I can show $$\langle a | c\rangle+\langle b| c\rangle=(\langle a|+\langle b|)\,|c\rangle$$

But I don't understand why the bra transformations $\langle P|$ ,$\langle Q|$ obey
$$\left(\langle P|+ \langle Q|\right)x = \langle P|x + \langle Q|x \quad .$$
Is it an assumption?

Comment: You mean "The linear functionals..."?

Comment: $\langle b+c\rangle$ is an average value and $\ne \langle b\vert c\rangle$ so is there a typo somewhere ?

Comment: Linearity of functionals is postulated, yes.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, yes I corrected it. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @DanielC, you mean if P, Q are linear transformations then its defined that (P+Q)b =Pb+Qb ?

Comment: @Kashmiri Indeed, $\forall b:(P+Q)b=Pb+Qb$ is the definition of $P+Q$.

Comment: Can you tell me what the book is? I didn't see Riesz theorem before. I find the book interesting. Can you give me the name of the book?

Comment: @narip, I think it’s ballentine

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it.

Comment: The books author is leslie ballentine

Answer (score 1):

> Is it an assumption?

I would rather say that
$$\forall x\in V:(\langle P|+ \langle Q|)x = \langle P|x + \langle Q|x$$
is the **definition** of $\langle P|+\langle Q|\in V'$. More generally, given $A,B\in V'$, then $A+B\in V'$ is defined by
$$\forall x\in V:(A+ B)x = Ax + Bx.$$

Answer (score 0):

First, How does the equation $1.8$ came about?

The inner product gives us a way to identify $V^*$ from $V$. If the field is complex, means there is an anti-linear correspondence between the two spaces. The vector $x\in V$ is mapped to $\langle x,\ \ \rangle $ which, since it returns a number when a vector is inserted into its vacant slot, is an element of $V^*$. This mapping is anti-linear because
$$\lambda x+\mu y\rightarrow \langle \lambda x+\mu y,\ \ \rangle =\lambda^*\langle x,\ \ \rangle +\mu^*\langle y,\ \ \rangle $$
This anti-linear map in quantum mechanics describe by saying that each vector $|\psi\rangle $ is mapped to it's dual
$$|\psi\rangle \rightarrow |\psi\rangle^\dagger \equiv \langle \psi|$$

---

The
$$(\langle \phi_1|+\langle \phi_2|)c=\langle \phi_1|c+\langle \phi_2|c$$
follow from the definition of vector space and $V^*$ is vector space.

Answer (score 0):

The distributive property is axiomatic to all [inner product spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space), but it feels backwards to say that's the reason. A better instruction would be to confirm with a Hamiltonian you have a good feel for that it fulfills the requirements for an inner product space. An even better instruction would be remind you, whenever you encounter a new Hamiltonian, to confirm that it fulfills the requirements for an inner product space.

The real reason is that it's defined to be an inner product space [with all that entails], and it gives great answers for the situations where it's appropriate.